# Comparing groups in glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I have a data set where I am trying to predict the survival of groups of animals after a temperature treatment they were exposed to and including species and life stage (juvenile and adult) as predictors. An example of the data are as follows but is greatly abbreviated:

```
    Species  Life Stage   Treatment Alive Dead
    ostrina     Juvenile    36      0   10
    ostrina     Juvenile    36      0   10
    ostrina     Juvenile    36      0   9
    ostrina     Juvenile    36      0   10
    ostrina     Adult       28      10  0
    ostrina     Adult       28      10  0
    ostrina     Adult       28      9   1
    ostrina     Adult       28      10  0
    trossulus   Juvenile    35      9   2
    trossulus   Juvenile    38      0   10
    trossulus   Juvenile    38      0   10
    trossulus   Juvenile    38      0   11
    trossulus   Juvenile    38      0   11
    trossulus   Adult       29      10  0
    trossulus   Adult       29      10  0
    trossulus   Adult       29      10  0
    trossulus   Adult       29      10  0
    trossulus   Adult       32      10  0
```

To do so I generated a model with the formula:

```
specmod=glm((cbind(Alive, Dead))~Treatment+Life.Stage+Species, data=alldat, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(specmod)
```

The output of this formula in r provides significance values for all parameters but also a p-value for each group (each species and life stage). This contrast is made to one level of each parameter in the model (the intercept) and can be re-leveled to contrast to other groups. There are three levels of `Life.Stage` (Juvenile, Intermediate, Adult) and four levels of `Species` (ostrina, glandula, trossulus, dalli).

```
Call:
glm(formula = (cbind(Alive, Dead)) ~ Treatment + Life.Stage + 
    Species, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = alldat)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-13.0311   -1.2937    0.1759    1.1406    4.0373  

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)            35.18325    1.78628  19.696  < 2e-16 ***
Treatment              -0.77341    0.03921 -19.726  < 2e-16 ***
Life.StageIntermediate  0.46494    0.26752   1.738  0.08221 .  
Life.StageJuvenile     -0.47258    0.17496  -2.701  0.00691 ** 
Speciesglandula        -2.15692    0.26365  -8.181 2.81e-16 ***
Speciesostrina         -9.66907    0.53008 -18.241  < 2e-16 ***
Speciestrossulus       -6.57073    0.40252 -16.324  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1761.17  on 166  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  645.44  on 160  degrees of freedom
AIC: 777.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

My questions are as follows:

**Do the p-values provided for each level of each parameter (eg. `Life.StageJuvenile` test the difference between groups where in this case the intercept would be the reference level which would be `Life.StageAdult` `dalli`?**  If this is true, how are the groups compared with a glm? Is it comparing the log-odds ratios of the groups?

I'm concerned about the difference in survival between groups of different species and life stages, so for example for the p-value of `Life.StageJuvenile` from the output, can I conclude that this group is significantly different than the Intercept which in this case is `Life.StageAdult`?

Comment: If youre really interested in only prediction, the p-values are not useful.

Comment: I'm primarily concerned with comparing the survival of survival after temperature treatments between groups ('levels') of species and life stages. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Check out the [`multcomp`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=multcomp) package, it has the `glht` function which may give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Or the **lsmeans** package

Comment: @hamilthj what is temperature treatment - a continuous variable e.g. 20 degree , 25  etc.

Comment: it's a continuous variable

Answer (score 2):

I deduct there are only 3 factor levels for life-stage. It looks like "lifestage" uses "adult" as the referent level, meaning that the contrasts created by the GLM compare intermediate to adult and juvenile to adult. I think your concept of "intercept" is referent level. As you'll see, logistic regression has a very specific concept of an intercept.

The statistical significance of the juvenile term means there is a difference in survival between adults and juveniles of the same species who receive the same treatment. This is the correct interpretation of effects in multivariate adjusted models with balanced design or simple random sampling.

The intercept (the term `(Intercept)` in the output)  is a log-odds of the outcome for an adult, not receiving treatment, and of the 4th unlisted species. Your odds ratio for the `Life.StageJuvenile` does *not* compare all juveniles to this group. I think your intuition of the effect is almost right, it simply is not the intercept, but the referent level (adult, unspecified species, unspecified treatment).

To see an example of a different contrast, modify the formula by specifying. `(cbind(Alive, Dead)) ~ 0 + Treatment + Life.Stage + 
    Species, family = binomial(link = "logit")`

If you want a treatment specific and/or species specific comparison, you will need to fit stratified models or control for interaction terms. This is good practice for such statistical analyses as it verifies a hidden assumption of homogeneity of effects (that is that the stratum specific effects approximately match the overall adjusted effect).

Comment: To clarify the third paragraph of your answer, the intercept is different from the reference level that the groups (eg. `Life.StageJuvenile`) are being contrasted against to calculate a p-value?

Comment: For the fourth paragraph with the code, what reference level are you setting? Does this just compare all groups with 0?

Comment: @hamilthj yes, as I mentioned the intercept is specific to each reference level in your model: treatment/species/lifestage. "Adults" have 8 risk levels: 2 level treatment by 4 level species. The Juvenille vs. Adult effect is a weighted average of the difference across all 8 levels. Setting `0+` in formula changes contrasts for the leading term so all effects are log odds and the hypothesis is whether they are different from 0 (corr. risk is different from 0.5).

Comment: Sorry I think I'm more confused by that answer. What is the two level treatment and where does the 8 levels come from?

Comment: @hamilthj my mistake I confused treatment for a 2 level factor. It is a continuous covariate, so in this case the intercept is a log odds predicted for an adult of the 4th species class (unlisted) receiving 0 treatment.

Comment: can we continue this in chat? I'm still confused on a few things that don't specifically regard your answer

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the last para, your conclusion is invalid. The GLM procedure does not invoke intercept for comparing it against a particular group estimate.
(  FURTHER refer to your last but one paragraph). The Pr value (for z) does not test the intercept. The GLM method compares groups with mean estimate to generate a maximum likelihood estimate.